# Why is the new keyword used twice to create object arrays

Tags: java, arrays, keyword

I am new to Java and I have just dealt with object arrays.  I'm curious as to why Java requires me to use the following syntax for arrays

```
SomeClass[] object = new SomeClass[50]; // any positive integer works
object[2] = new SomeClass(some, parameters);
```

As I understand it, the *new* keyword allocates the data for the instance in memory.  I was wondering why Java uses the *new* keyword twice here.  I think it should only have to use the new keyword once when the objects are initialized and not when they are declared.  So, my question is: why does Java use the new keyword twice when creating object arrays?

Comment: One for creating the array, one for creating the object SomeClass that will be store at the position 3 in the array (index 2).

Comment: Because you're creating _two_ things.

Comment: Thanks; I get it now.  I thought the first line was dealing with the class I created and not the array it was storing values in.  I guess I might have thought of it sooner if normal arrays (String, int, etc.) used the new keyword.  Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: _All_ arrays are created using `new`.  There is no such thing as a "normal" array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the `new` keyword is used twice because two objects are being created -- one array and one `SomeClass` that happens to be placed in the array.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised I never thought of it that way before.  Since the array syntax leads to creating an Array object, it creates the array object there. I wouldn't have thought of that ;)

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... Building a box than can holds 50 balls, doesn't mean that there is 50 balls inside. You have to create a new ball each time you want to put it in the box.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is to create an array of references. The second one is to create the actual object for every element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the *container* (an array in your case), and each *element* (which is also an *object*) that you intend to place in that container.

In your case, I note you've created an array with 50 elements. That means that you can *index* `object[0]` up to and including `object[49]`. When the container is created, each `object[n]` will be a `null` reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeClass[] object = new SomeClass[50];
```

allocates an array with 50 uninitialized references

```
object[2] = new SomeClass(some, parameters);
```

allocates and instantiates an object referred to by the third index in the array